# Google Apps Script error "Exception: You do not have permission to access the requested document. (line 14)."

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to create a function in the Google Spreadsheet for my coworkers to extract URL's from hyperlinks easily using the "GetURL" function. This is the code I have:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Chris') // your name
  .addItem("Activate Chris's script", 'activateMyStuff')
  .addToUi();
}

function activateMyStuff() {
  browser.msgBox('Script is activated! thanks.');
}

function GetURL(input) {
  var myFormula = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getFormula();
  var myAddress = myFormula.replace('=GetURL(','').replace(')','');
  var myRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(myAddress);
  return myRange.getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()
 }
```

The first part of the script is to give everyone permissions to run the script and the second part of the function is for the GetURL function. Unfortunately, when I run the script and use the GetURL formula, I get an error stating: Exception: You do not have permission to access the requested document. (line 14). I have given everyone editor access to the spreadsheet and when I run the custom script, another error also occurs stating: ReferenceError: browser is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to **"ReferenceError: browser is not defined"**, "**Browser**" is a class, so it is capitalized.

I think you are a bit confused about how the [getUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/service#getUrl()) function works;
It is used to get the URL of a Google Apps Script web application, not to get a URL from a cell.

To get the URL from a cell, you just have to read it as a text using `getValue()`.

Your code should look like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Chris') // your name
  .addItem("Activate Chris's script", 'activateMyStuff')
  .addToUi();
}

function activateMyStuff() {
  Browser.msgBox('Script is activated! thanks.');
}

function getURL() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue();
}
```